# How to specify figure sizes by using fig_height & fig_width in R Notebook

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown, rnotebook

I encounter a problem about the figure size when I using R Notebook.

The fig_height & fig_width did not work in html_notebook when I set the fig_height: 2 &fig_width: 2 as below.

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  html_notebook:
   fig_height: 2 
   fig_width: 2
---

# test

## test2
```{r}
plot(cars)
```
````

[The R Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST97G.png)

But if I change the html_notebook to html_document, the fig_height & fig_width will become as I need.

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  html_document:
    fig_height: 2 
    fig_width: 2
---

# test

## test2
```{r}
plot(cars)
```
````

[The R Markdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8zk0.png)

Does it mean R Notebook can not use fig_height: &fig_width: at the beginning ?? Or I do something wrong??

I using Rstudio 1.1.383, R version 3.4.2. and mac OS HIGH Sierra.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: You should include source for a small example in your question so people can try it out.  The picture is too inconvenient to get text from.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I will edit it right away~